# Which statistical test for two group proportions over two time periods? 100% sampling, capped membership. Independent groups over time

Tags: logistic, statistical-significance, anova, chi-squared-test, proportion

I'm comparing the number of male and female hires at a city in the 1980's to the number of male and female hires in the 1990's.  I'm looking for whether the percentage of females increased significantly. Specifically, the research question is, did the percentage of female hires increase in the 1990's. 
The total number of hires increased by about 20% in the 1990's.  The total number of males hired, overall is 1800, vs. females at 1200.

So there are 4 numbers:
   The number of males hired in the 1980's = M1
   The number of males hired in the 1990's = M2
   The number of females hired in the 1980's = F1
   The number of females hired in the 1980's = F2

Null hypothesis: There is no change in the percentage of female hires at city X, for the total number of hires in the 1980's, and the total number of hires in the 1990's.

Alternative hypothesis: The percentage of female hires increased. (One-tailed.)

What statistical test do I use (and how)?

The two-proportion z-test requires random sampling, and a universe size that is at least 20 times larger than the sample.  Chi squared seems to require random sampling, and it also seems to require independence of selection - and in this scenario there is a fixed, but increasing number of employees, and each slot gets filled by one or the other.